# Select item from table

Tags: karate

[image]

Trying to search for FirstName 'Tony' and select a Check box against that name

xpath for table body is - "//*[@id='searchAndEditStorelist'"

*When def list1 = scriptAll('tr td','_.textContent') is giving all the rows in tr td format

But How to search the First Name and click the checkbox  against that when **more than one Table** present in the page and same text is present in different row

like using some function
*When def list2 = scriptAll('tr td,'_.textContent',function(x){ return x.contains('Tony') })

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Karate has some ways to iterate over a list, refer: https://github.com/intuit/karate#json-transforms

And you can get the index of the item. Now you should be able to use an XPath for the correct row of the table. Something like this:

```
* def list = scriptAll('tr td', '_.textContent')    
* def fun = function(x, i){ if (x.contains('Tony')) karate.set('index', i) }
# I am guessing some xpath here, please change accordingly
* def xpath = "//input[@type='checkbox'][" + (index + 1) + "]"
* click(xpath)
```

Comment: The above worked but if there are two table in the same page how scriptAll('tr td', '_.textContent') will understand which table to look.Is there anyway we can pass the table xpath?  Also if I need to look x.contains('Tony') only in second column of each row how to do that ? scriptAll('tr td[1]', '_.textContent') didn't worked.